# How to display correctly error bars in matplotlib? Mine are visually wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I observe a little strange thing when plotting, my error bars go over the cap.
See on the image below, especially on the top plot:

[image: Hubble Diagram]

The command I used for the error bars is:

```
f.errorbar(zcmb,mufinal,linestyle='',xerr=dz,yerr=dmufinal,ecolor='black')
```

and similar for the others subplots.

When zooming, this error vanishes...

Has someone seen this before?

Comment: There is no uploaded picture in your post, please edit your post.

Comment: Yes there is, sorry I miss the first time but I edited quickly ! Thanks for your attention by the way

Comment: Looks like a minor bug.

Comment: Sure, but any idea how to solve it ? Thanks tom for the edition of my first post.